# Textos alinhados no canto direito inferior da tela

Tags: html, css

Como deixar dois textos alinhados no canto inferior direito da tela em css, um em cada linha, exemplo:

```
           IVP
Inventory Variant Position
```

IVP centralizado logo acima do significado, porém ambos no canto inferior direito.

Tentei assim, mas sem sucesso:

```
<div class='page test-page' id='ivp-page-1'>
    <h3>IVP</h3>
    <h4>INVENTORY VARIANT POSITION</h4>
</div>

h3, h4 {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    min-width: 825px;
    height:700px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-left:3.7%;
    margin-right:3.7%;
    padding-left:0.5%;
    padding-right:0.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer e usando `position:absolute` para colocar a div inteira no canto direito inferior e `text-align:center` no texto para alinhar da forma que vc quer.

**OBS:** repare que vc não deve usar `width` na `div` ok, pois come ela está com `position:absolute` ela assume a largura do maior conteúdo que está dentro, a largura máxima então é a do maior texto e o outro texto menor fica centralizado no texto maior entende.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.test-page {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
h3, h4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='page test-page' id='ivp-page-1'>
    <h3>IVP</h3>
    <h4>INVENTORY VARIANT POSITION</h4>
</div>
```